# C# First Special Char

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to write a calculator just for the fun of it, the first bit is quite easy.
Making it do the calculations, even with more of the same type calculations, ex 10+10+10
My problem comes when I try to figuer out how to do this when it comes in a long string with diffrendt calculations methods..

Ex 10+15-5, and 10-15+5 gives to very diffrendt ressults. But at the moment I cant archive this since my code dosent support diffrendt calculation methods in the same string, so I need a way to look at what calculation methods was posted in the string.

I'm using a .split('-','+') on the string, but that leaves me in a porblem, I have no way to look for what char was the first I split the string on, so I dont know what method to call..

I'm figureing that the final thing would be something like this.

```
If(stringSplitChar == +)
{
     int tempRes;

     tempRes = Convert.ToInt32(SplitVal[0]);

     for (i = 1; i < SplitVal.Count(); i++)
     {
         tempRes = addVal(tempRes, Convert.ToInt32(SplitVal[i]));
     }

     endRes = tempRes.ToString(););
}

endRes = temp;

return endRes;
```

Comment: If you want to support more than addition and subtraction this method does not scale.  You need an expression tree, to handle order of operations.

Comment: *10+15-5, and 10-15+5 gives to very diffrendt ressults.* - isn't that a good thing?

Comment: Well yes it is, I might not have been to clear in this, yes its a good thing they give to diffrendt resoults, but at the moment I cant get them to put out the right resoults, since I have no way to check what calculation method was posted in the string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn parsing, syntax tree, ...

You can take a look at existing project to understand how it works.  [ncalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

To be Fair You need get Nos. Separately, If you want to do this without...

```
      using System;
      using System.Data;

      class Program {
      static void Main(string[] args) {
      string s ="10+20+30"
      var dt = new DataTable();
      var result = dt.Compute(s, null);

       }
      }
```

Comment: OP : `I'm trying to write a calculator just for the fun of it` ;)